# HTML5 Video - On Hover / Off Hover return to poster image?

Tags: html, video

I'm working on an sandbox experiment using html5 video and am wondering how I can get the poster image to display after again once the end user hovers off the video?

I have the video setup so that if you hover over the video can auto play and if you hover off it stops. I would like it to return back to poster image.

*Javascript*

```
<script>

document.addEventListener('mouseover',hoverVideo,false);
var vid = document.getElementById('vid1');

function hoverVideo(a)
{    
    if(a.target == vid)
    {
        vid.play();
        this.addEventListener('mouseout',hideVideo,false);
    }

}
function hideVideo(e)
{
    if(e.target == vid)
    {
        vid.pause();
    }

}

</script>
```

*HTML5*

```
<video id="vid1" width="1000" height="418" 
poster="poster.png" loop="true" preload="auto"
controls class="video-js vjs-default-skin">

 <source src="my_video.mp4" type='video/mp4' >
 <source src="my_video.webm" type='video/webm' />
 <source src="my_video.ogv" type='video/ogg' />

</video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (you'll need to include jQuery)

```
function hideVideo(e)
{
    if(e.target == vid)
    {
        vid.pause();
        var poster = $(vid).attr("poster");
        $(vid).attr("poster", "");
        $(vid).attr("poster", poster);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! That sort of did it! I had to change $("#vid1").attra("poster", "http://imageurl");, but the thing is when I go to hover over the image a second time the video disappears.